# ¿como aplicar CSS a la pestaña que este activa si esto no funciona?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, nextjs, next

Estoy en NextJS version 13,quiero hacer algo que en teoria parecia simple. Quiero que al hacer click en un hipervinculo de mi pagina, al hipervinculo seleccionado se le aplique un color azul de un css, para señalar que esa pestaña es la esta activa.

Este es component padre:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
import Link from "next/link";
import styles from './NavBar.module.css'

import { ActiveLink } from "./ActiveLink";

export const NavBar = () => {
  return (<>
      <nav className={styles.menuConteiner}>
        <ActiveLink href={'/'} text={'Home'}/>
        <ActiveLink href={'/about'} text={'About'}/>
        <ActiveLink href={'/contact'} text={'Contact'}/>
      </nav>
  </>);
};
```

Este el componente hijo,este componente tiene un css almacenado en una variable `style`, el cual sera aplicado a la pestaña que este activa:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
'use client'

import Link from "next/link"
import { usePathname } from "next/navigation"

const style = {
  color: '#0070f3',
  textDecoration: 'underline',
}

export const ActiveLink = ({text, href}) =>{
  const pathname = usePathname()
  return(
    <Link href={href} style={pathname === href ? style : null}>{text}</Link>
  )
}
```

Pero al intentar renderizar esto, no se muestra nada, todoesta en blanco y aparece un error:
[image: Imagen-error]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intente muchos enfoques para que esto funcionara, pero no hay caso. Despues de mucho intentar, el error es sin lugar a dudas este:

```
import { usePathname } from "next/navigation"
            
    const pathname = usePathname()
            
    <Link href={href} style={pathname === href ? style : null}>{text}</Link>
```

Este codigo pertenece al componente hijo como podran observar, esto es lo que origina el problema, en teoria esto permite que al seleccionar una pestaña, este pasa a tener las propiedades del css 'style', pero no funciona. ¿Alguno sabe como solucionar esto?, o bien, ¿conoce otra forma de seleccionar pesteñas y que se le aplique un css?

Comment: Dices que "en teoria esto permite que al seleccionar una pestaña..." ¿Ya confirmaste eso en la doc? Parece que el componente ActiveLink esta envolviendo a ese `Link`, entonces puede que ActiveLink no te permita ver el cambio en Link porque lo envuelve?